# LinkedList toString()

Tags: java, linked-list, subclass

I have implemented a program that stores sets within a `Linkedlist`. When I print out the linked lists, I get, for example, `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

What I want is to change the square brackets to braces e.g. '{' & '}'

I can't use string manipulations so I MUST override the `toString` method.

I am clueless on how to do this other than the fact I know i must create a subclass. It's the method itself that baffles me.

```
public class outputSets
    {    
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes", "unused" })
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {    
        LinkedList x0 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList x1 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList x2 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList x3 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList x4 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList x5 = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList x6 = new LinkedList();

        x0.add(new Integer(8));

        for(int i=1; i<8; i++)
        {
            x1.add(new Integer(i));
        }

        x1.add((x0.getFirst()));

        x2.addAll(x1);
        x2.add(new Pair(1, x1));

        x3.add(new Pair(x2,x1));

        //x4.addAll(tree.union(x3, x2));

        //x5.add(tree.difference(x4, x1));

        //x6.add(tree.intersection(x4, x1));
        /*
        Iterator i0 = x0.listIterator();
        Iterator i1 = x0.listIterator();
        Iterator i2 = x0.listIterator();
        Iterator i3 = x0.listIterator();
        Iterator i4 = x0.listIterator();
        Iterator i5 = x0.listIterator();
        Iterator i6 = x0.listIterator();
        */

        System.out.print(x0.getFirst());
        System.out.println();
        SetArray(x1);
        System.out.println();
        SetArray(x2);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
      }


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static void SetArray(LinkedList x0)
    {
        for(int index=0; index < x0.size() ; index++)
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                System.out.print(x0.get(index));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(", " +
                        "" + x0.get(index));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A linked list is a pretty poor implementation of a set, since adding a new element, deleting an element, and checking for set inclusion are all linear-time operations.  Maybe you should use a hash table or a tree instead (or use one of Java's built-in set implementations, which are based on hash tables and trees).

Comment: I googled 'java linkedlist source' and the 1st one points to source. But the 2nd one was Sun source and had clickable links to find parent classes. I found the source you could use here: [AbstractCollection.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.java.html)

Comment: What is the reason that you cannot use string manipulations?

Comment: I suggest you don't bother. Use the default. Otherwise you have to write code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is completely dependent on the implementation of [`AbstractCollection.toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29) - which `LinkedList` (and most other collections except maps) inherits. This implementation looks like this (slightly simplified):

```
public String toString() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (! it.hasNext())
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[');
    for (;;) {
        E e = it.next();
        sb.append(e);
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return sb.append(']').toString();
        sb.append(", ");
    }
}
```

Having this as a guideline it should be pretty straightforward for you to create your own implementation that does not include square brackets. You can either create your own collection that overrides `toString()` or have a separate utility method taking your `LinkedList input` as an argument (in that case obviously replace `iterator()` with `input.iterator()`).

Answer (score 4):

You could also create a helper method which takes `List` object as an attribute and returns `String` with concatenated contents of this list. That way inheritance is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that `extends LinkedList` and contains a method like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {

}
```

The method can access the list items like this:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = this.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()) {
    Integer nextItem = it.next();
}
```

Comment: Dont tell me.. .. I didnt give all the code but should be enough info here to get going

Comment: It seems to me that extending LinkedList is a bit of overkill. Don't you think so?

Comment: he said he "must" Override toString

Comment: ye thats what i have, my problem is i dont know what to put inside the toString method. im not asking for the answer only advice